# check a function is exist in rootscope in angular js

Tags: angularjs

I have a condition in my angular project where i have to check if a function inside of rootscope is exist then it will execute otherwise it will go to else condition but it is showing me error "$rootScope.getTodaysSteps is not a function". i want to know how to check if a function exist or not in rootscope

```
         if(typeof $rootScope.getTodaysSteps() !== "undefined"){
               $rootScope.getTodaysSteps();

             } else{
                   $rootScope.isDataSyncing = false;
             }
```

Comment: So if you want to know if the function exist , why do you call it then - `typeof $rootScope.getTodaysSteps()`? Just check `typeof $rootScope.getTodaysSteps`

Comment: yes i didnot removed ()  :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
if (typeof $rootScope.getTodaysSteps !== 'undefined' && typeof $rootScope.getTodaysSteps === 'function') 
{ 
     ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

if (angular.isFunction($rootScope.getTodaysSteps()) == true) {

```
   $rootScope.getTodaysSteps();
```

} else{

```
  $rootScope.isDataSyncing = false;
```

}